# How do I make a vertical slider in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I can't change the structure of HTML code itself, because it is formed with PHP, so I can't use something like swiper slider. The only way out is through JavaScript or jq to do it. I'm not very good at writing code myself yet, but if you have code examples I could use

```css
ol, ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.flex-control-nav {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  margin: 10px 0;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<div class="woocommerce-product-gallery">
  <ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-thumbs">
    <li><img src="https://static7.depositphotos.com/1000695/734/i/600/depositphotos_7343574-stock-photo-kitten-on-a-white-background.jpg" class="flex-active"></li>
    <li><img src="https://static7.depositphotos.com/1000695/734/i/600/depositphotos_7343574-stock-photo-kitten-on-a-white-background.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="https://static7.depositphotos.com/1000695/734/i/600/depositphotos_7343574-stock-photo-kitten-on-a-white-background.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="https://static7.depositphotos.com/1000695/734/i/600/depositphotos_7343574-stock-photo-kitten-on-a-white-background.jpg"></li>
  </ol>

  <ul class="flex-direction-nav">
    <li class="flex-nav-prev"><a class="flex-prev flex-disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1">Previous</a></li>
    <li class="flex-nav-next"><a class="flex-next" href="#">Next</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Simply set `overflow-y:scroll` to your flex-control-nav.

Answer (score 0):

**Way 1**

The easy way to vertically slide the images is to set a `height` to the `<ol>` and make the `ovelflow-y: scroll`. This will let you scroll vertically to the next images.

**Way 2**

As your code contains *Prev* and *Next* links, in order to use these links to prev and next the images vertically [javaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_next_prev.asp) is needed, but is is simple one. By listening the [click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event) event of the buttons we can set the vertical alignment of the images by setting the property `transform: translateY({num}%)` on the images(technically the `li` element that contains the image).

Here is and example code as you asked :

```js
const imgSlides = document.querySelectorAll(".pic");
const nextBtn = document.querySelector(".next");
const prevBtn = document.querySelector(".prev");

let counter = 0;
nextBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    counter++;
    carouse();
})
prevBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    counter--;
    carouse();
})
function carouse(){
    if(counter < imgSlides.length -1){
        nextBtn.disabled = false;
    }
    else{
        nextBtn.disabled = true; //Disabling the next button if the current image is the last image
    }
    if(counter > 0){
        prevBtn.disabled = false;
    }
    else{
        prevBtn.disabled = true;  //Disabling the prev button if the current image is the first image
    }

    //Changing the images vertical positon based on the counter value
    imgSlides.forEach(function(slide){
        slide.style.transform = `translateY(-${counter*100}%)`
    })
}
prevBtn.disabled = true;
```

```css
body{
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
ol{
    list-style: none;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border: 2px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
ol li{

    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.pic{
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

/*The below code will put the images vertically one below the other*/
ol li:nth-child(2){
        transform: translateY(100%);
}
ol li:nth-child(3){
    transform: translateY(200%);
}
ol li:nth-child(4){
    transform: translateY(300%);
}
.buttons{
    display: flex;
    gap: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <title>Vertical Image Slide</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <ol>
          <li><img src="https://static7.depositphotos.com/1000695/734/i/600/depositphotos_7343574-stock-photo-kitten-on-a-white-background.jpg" alt="" class="pic"></li>
          <li><img src="https://static7.depositphotos.com/1000695/734/i/600/depositphotos_7343574-stock-photo-kitten-on-a-white-background.jpg" alt="" class="pic"></li>
          <li><img src="https://static7.depositphotos.com/1000695/734/i/600/depositphotos_7343574-stock-photo-kitten-on-a-white-background.jpg" alt="" class="pic"></li>
          <li><img src="https://static7.depositphotos.com/1000695/734/i/600/depositphotos_7343574-stock-photo-kitten-on-a-white-background.jpg" alt="" class="pic"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="buttons">
          <button class="btn prev">Prev</button>
          <button class="next">Next</button>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What if the number of pictures can always be different?

Comment: For that just add 
`imgSlides.forEach(function(slide, index){
    slide.style.top = \`${index*100}%\`
});`
in the **js** file first and **delete** the 
`ol li:nth-child(#){
    transform: translate(#%);
}` 
part from the **css** file.

Comment: I did as you wrote and it doesn't work

Comment: Sorry, it is because the image is not positioned absolutely which means `top` property doesn't work on elements that are not absolutely positioned but the `li` is absolute so, the js has to be like this           `const listSlides = document.querySelectorAll("ol li");

        listSlides.forEach(function(slide, index){
            slide.style.top = \`${index * 100}%\`
        })`